# Is there an EmberJS addon that runs the app in a try/catch and externally logs unhandled errors?

Tags: ember.js, error-handling

I'd like to have a system like Crashlytics where I can monitor unhandled errors that my users encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an ember plugin/addon, but Sentry provides what you're looking for: https://getsentry.com/for/ember/

I'm sure there are other libs/providers out there. A quick google query takes me here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-airbrake

Comment: We use raven plugin from sentry. https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js/tree/master/plugins

Comment: Just upgraded to the new version of ember-cli-deploy and hooked https://github.com/netguru/ember-cli-deploy-rollbar up. Great thing is Rollbar supports source maps (which this addon uploads on deploy) and has a free tier available.

Answer (score 2):

You can register a function that is called whenever an uncaught error happens via the `Ember.onerror` hook.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/debugging/#toc_implement-an-ember-onerror-hook-to-log-all-errors-in-production